# Magento 1.9.3 admin custom page URL redirect to dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, custom, page

I have creating a custom page in admin side. When i try to access that page automatically redirect to `dashboard`

my code is following:

`app\code\local\EPayment\EPayment\controllers\Adminhtml\EpaymentbackendController.php`

```
<?php
class EPayment_EPayment_Adminhtml_EpaymentbackendController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function historyAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout() ; 
        $this->renderLayout(); 
        //Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());die;
    }
}
```

`app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\epayment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

  <epayment_adminhtml_epaymentbackend_history>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="epayment/adminhtml_epaymentbackend" name="epaymentbackend" template="epayment/history.phtml"/>
    </reference>
  </epayment_adminhtml_epaymentbackend_history>

</layout>
```

`app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\epayment\history.phtml`

```
<div class="content-header">
    <table cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td><h3 class="icon-head head-sales-order">Epayment History</h3></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

`app\code\local\EPayment\EPayment\etc\config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <EPayment_EPayment>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </EPayment_EPayment>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <epayment>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>EPayment_EPayment</module>
            <frontName>epayment</frontName>
          </args>
      </epayment>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <epayment>
              <file>epayment.xml</file>
            </epayment>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <epayment>
        <class>EPayment_EPayment_Helper</class>
      </epayment>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <epayment>
        <class>EPayment_EPayment_Block</class>
      </epayment>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <epayment>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>EPayment_EPayment</module>
          <frontName>admin_epayment</frontName>
        </args>
      </epayment>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
      <epayment module="epayment">
        <title>EPayment</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <epaymentbackend module="epayment">
            <title>EPayment</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>admin_epayment/adminhtml_epaymentbackend</action>
          </epaymentbackend>
        </children>
      </epayment>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <epayment translate="title" module="epayment">
              <title>EPayment</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
          <epaymentbackend translate="title">
            <title>EPayment</title>
          </epaymentbackend>
              </children>
            </epayment>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <epayment>
          <file>epayment.xml</file>
        </epayment>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Page `URL`
`http://127.0.0.1/mathu/magento/index.php/admin_epayment/adminhtml_epaymentbackend/history/key/574480610c547e2835f47af6ccb85888/`

I know i did small mistake.

Please help me

Comment: can you share your config.xml file

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala: Updated please check

Answer (score 2):

As a best practice suggested by Magento, you should not create new router for Magento admin panel. Instead you should ask Magento to read your module's controller before reading the core controller. For this, you need to modify your `config.xml` slightly as mentioned below:

`app/code/local/EPayment/EPayment/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    .....
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <epayment before="Mage_Adminhtml">EPayment_EPayment_Adminhtml</epayment>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    ......
</config>
```

The next thing is admin menus should be defined in `adminhtml.xml`. Even though this is not mandatory, it is a best practice suggested by Magento.

Since we have modified the controller definition in `config.xml`, your menu URL will become `adminhtml/epaymentbackend/history`. This needs to be updated in the menu definition as follows:

`app/code/local/EPayment/EPayment/etc/adminhtml.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
    <menu>
        <epayment module="epayment">
            <title>EPayment</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <epaymentbackend module="epayment">
                    <title>EPayment</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/epaymentbackend/history</action>
                </epaymentbackend>
            </children>
        </epayment>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <epayment translate="title" module="epayment">
                        <title>EPayment</title>
                        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <epaymentbackend translate="title">
                                <title>EPayment</title>
                            </epaymentbackend>
                        </children>
                    </epayment>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Based on the new menu URL, your layout file should be modified as below:

`app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\epayment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_epaymentbackend_history>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="epayment/adminhtml_epaymentbackend" name="epaymentbackend" template="epayment/history.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_epaymentbackend_history>
</layout>
```

Comment: Karthik i have already  added `adminhtml.xml` in `config.xml` athu correct ah ilaya ?

Comment: @MuduK `adminhtml.xml` is a separate file. Remove the menu related contents from `config.xml` and place them in `adminhtml.xml` as suggested in my reply.

Comment: Yeah its working

Comment: Block loaded in `localhost` but same code not working in live server. I mean block not loding

Comment: @MuduK Which block is not loading ?

Comment: See This:  https://ibb.co/kxFUAR

Comment: Same code working in local look this https://ibb.co/jgiPAR

Comment: @MuduK Do you have error reporting enabled in your server ? I think there must be some error thrown but it is not visible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70557/discussion-between-mudu-k-and-n-karthic-kannan).

Comment: worked as charm, something like supee related issue. saved my day